# SVF file format spec or processing library

Tags: autodesk-forge

Does Autodesk provide a specification or library for working with SVF files output by the Forge API? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: can you clarify what/why you need this?

Comment: To render the SVF format in a C++ application/viewer.

Comment: please check if the answer and comment help you, if not, let me know.

Comment: I would like to use the SVF format to deliver the content to be used and manipulated in a 3D C++ application, since all uploaded objects can be extracted in that format. From what I gather, that is not possible.

Comment: I don't really see why this question was closed. The close reason is for people asking for "recommendations" - this question is not doing so; it is a totally answerable, objective question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now (August/2016), we don't have a public specification of the SVF format used on the [Forge Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2), but the downloaded version follows the Three.js. If you need a local (offline) version, you can use this [Extractor](http://extract.autodesk.io).

To show that on your application (as you mentioned, a C++), you can host a WebControl and include on it the online or offline version of the Forge Viewer. I would not recommend you to implement your own render, but take advantage of webgl support.

Comment: You can also use the Model Derivative API to either translate your seed file to OBJ or to extract model components in the SVF file as OBJ files. Right now, this API only extracts mesh data, but we expect to add texture support 'soon'.

Comment: Am I reading this page correctly when I read that an uploaded OBJ cannot be downloaded as an OBJ, only an SVF?

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/